# Repeat task while activity is open

Tags: android

i want to repeat task while the activity is open.

For example repeat foo() every minute while the activity is open.

I tought about Timer, handler and runable.

I tought about this code:

Maybe there is some better way?

```
public void setRefreshRate()
        {
          newTimer = true
            while(true)
            {
                if(newTimer)
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        if(isNetworkAvailable() && movedToAnotherActivity== false)
                            new GetWorkouts().execute();

                        newTimer = true;
                    }
            }, Integer.getInteger(data.getWallRefresh()));

                    newTimer = false;

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way but I like `AsyncTask` so I would probably use that and call `sleep()` in `doInBackground()` then you can call `cancel()` on your task object and set it to `null` when the `Activity` finishes.

```
 public void doInBackground(Void...params)
{
    boolean flag = false;
    while (!flag)
    {
       // do some work
       Thread.sleep(6000);
    }
}
```

then overide and set `flag` to true in `onBackPressed()` and `finish()`. You can then use any of the other `AsyncTask` methods to update the `UI` if necessary.

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: A never-ending AsyncTask will block other AsyncTasks. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42000437/1982087

Comment: @JamesNickSears I wouldn't say this is the best way (4 years after writing the answer) but it's not blocking anything. The OP never said anything about running other tasks.

Comment: @codeMagic I spent awhile trying to figure out why my other task wasn't running after doing it this way. Just trying to help keep others from replicating the same confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [codeMagic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18243907/1982087) for starting me down the right path, but AsyncTask isn't really designed for this. From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

> AsyncTasks should ideally be used for short operations (a few seconds at the most.)

The problem is that AsyncTasks, at least by default, run sequentially on the same worker thread, so if you try to launch another AsyncTask, it won't be able to run, since the timer loop never finishes.

To work around this, I just used a raw Thread and it's working fine.

```
apiUpdateTimerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    try {
                        Log.i(TAG, "UPDATE FROM THE API!!!!");
                        doSomeStuff();

                        Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);
                    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "API Update AsyncTask Interrupted", e);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

To stop it, just call

```
apiUpdateTimerThread.interrupt();
```